# Android 10 - Weird activity lifecycle

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I have a weird issue that happens on Android 10, when I start new landscape activity, the activity below will recreate.

Assume there're two `Activity` classes:

```
ActivityA: orientation = unspecified
ActivityB: orientation = force landscape, full screen, opaque
```

If I start `ActivityB` from `ActivityA`, the logs of lifecycle event:

```
D/ActivityA: onPause() called
D/ActivityB: onCreate() called
D/ActivityB: onStart() called
D/ActivityB: onResume() called
D/ActivityA: onStop() called
D/ActivityA: onDestroy() called
D/ActivityA: onCreate() called
D/ActivityA: onStart() called
D/ActivityA: onResume() called
D/ActivityA: onPause() called
D/ActivityA: onStop() called
```

Can clearly see that `ActivityA` is recreated, moreover somehow `ActivityA#onResume` is called after `ActiviyB#onResume`??

Okay, so now we have `ActivityB` on top of the stack, then I press back button:

```
D/ActivityB: onPause() called
D/ActivityA: onStart() called
D/ActivityA: onResume() called
D/ActivityA: onPause() called
D/ActivityA: onStop() called
D/ActivityA: onDestroy() called
D/ActivityA: onCreate() called
D/ActivityA: onStart() called
D/ActivityA: onResume() called
D/ActivityB: onStop() called
D/ActivityB: onDestroy() called
```

`ActivityA` is recreated again?

As I see in my device, there's an animation that `ActivityA` rotates into landscape mode before `ActivityB` becomes visible, and when `ActivityB` exits, `ActivityA` again rotates back to portrait mode. This behavior may cause `ActivityA` recreate again and again.

It messes up a lot, do you know how to prevent `ActivityA` recreate on this case, or this is a bug of Android itself?

### UPDATE 1

I can handle configuration change on `ActivityA` easily, the problem is `ActivityA` has a very complex view structure, recreate it unnecessary causes UI lagging, moreover activity's lifecycle callback messy also cause broken logic.

### UPDATE 2

I just figured out that `recreate()` method is invoked twice by `AppCompatDelegateImpl` class, that's why I get weird lifecycle behavior:

[image]

Comment: Start activity B with flag Single top from activity A to force activity A to close

Comment: @alokHarman This comment makes no sense at all.

Comment: Please provide simple example code and the way you full screen your activity

Comment: What alokHarman means is to set android:launchMode=singleTop for the activity (q.v. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element), which is supposed to reuse an activity by re-firing an intent. But I'm dubious it will work here because of configuration change which forces destruction (see answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a device-specific bug.

I tried your code as it is on Pixel 3a (API 29 & 30) emulator. This is what I get:

On starting `ActivityB` from `ActivityA`:

```
D/MainActivityA: onPause() called
D/MainActivityB: onCreate() called
D/MainActivityB: onStart() called
D/MainActivityB: onResume() called
D/MainActivityA: onStop() called
```

On back button press:

```
D/MainActivityB: onPause() called
D/MainActivityA: onStart() called
D/MainActivityA: onResume() called
D/MainActivityB: onStop() called
D/MainActivityB: onDestroy() called
```

[image: No weird animation indicating ActivityA is changing orientation]

You should [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) with the appropriate Android build and Device used

**Thoughts on Update 2 in the question**:

The logs show that `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` is being called. [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes) points out that Activity will be recreated on runtime configuration changes.

What you can do is override `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` in your Activity and log the Configuration object to see what device configuration was changed. It  may be `Orientation`, `Screen size`, `ScreenLayout` or `Keyboard availability`

Comment: Thanks for testing it on your device, I just run a sample project and figure out it's not because of orientation, please see my update.

Answer (score 3):

Probably isn't much you can do about this behaviour. I would suggest the following, if it doesn't cause you too many problems:

- Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the manifest entry for `ActivityA`
- Implement `onConfigurationChanged()` in `ActivityA` and handle the orientation change yourself

This will prevent Android from killing and recreating `ActivityA` during an orientation change.

Comment: One more issue, I heavily rely on method `onResume` to determine which activity is visible on top of the stack, but with this behavior, ActivityA#onResume is called while it's behind ActivityB, it caused a lot of logic issue.

Answer (score 1):

it's not only you facing this problem (many people are) this is a bug which is to be fixed and it shouldn't be messed actually can I know which device you are using? In comment you may tell.

Comment: my device is Samsung M10, android 10, One UI 2.0

Comment: do you know any linked issue which is discussed somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Recreating activities on landscape/portrait is a feature of Android (not a bug) made by design because it's easier programmatically to just redraw the UI rather than figure out repositioning/resizing of elements. You should get the same effect when just flipping orientation on A even without B. This is also well described in the Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/state-changes#cco)

This shouldn't be too much of a problem, so long as you don't keep any references to the activity itself; The resources at this point are already cached, so there is little to no flash I/O, and most of the work will be recreating the views.

Comment: It looks more like a bug to me, what if ActivityA is designed for portrait mode only? And how can explains why ActivityA#onResume is called after ActivityB#onResume (ActivityA behind ActivityB).

Comment: From what you said, ActivityA could be either portrait or landscape (you noted 'unspecified'). Make it portrait only should stop the transition.

Answer (score 0):

Activity is recreated after each rotation by default as it's told on official Activity Lifecycle [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#ondestroy) documents.

If you expect the activity’s UI state to remain the same throughout a configuration change, such as rotation, you should preserve the user’s transient UI state using a combination of ViewModel, onSaveInstanceState(), and/or local storage as it's explained in the [Saving and restoring transient UI state](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras)

You can override this behavior with config changes attribute of the activity tag in AndroidManifest. For further details and different options, see [Handle configuration changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Finally, you can learn more about [Activity Lifecycle in Context of Screen Rotation](https://insomniacs.in/blog/understanding-activity-lifecycle-in-context-of-screen-rotation/) here.